# add tooltip to extjs grid to show complete information about that row

Tags: extjs, tooltip

I had a *gridview*, it attached with a model that have some fields. But in my grid i just show one field, and what i want is when my mouse hover to the grid row, *tooltip* will appear and show the other fields value.

How can i do this? Anybody ever done this?

What grid event that I should create the *tooltip*? How can I access my on hover row value and show it on the *tooltip*? How the nice ways to show the value, can *tooltip* using item like *xpanel* or something, or the only way is using html?

Please help me. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use renderer in grid columns config. write an function which will return the expected value to that renderer function mapping.

Sample working example:

```
columns: [{
           text     : 'Device Name',
           dataIndex: 'name',
           renderer: getExpandableImage        
         }]



function getExpandableImage(value, metaData,record){
    var deviceDetail = record.get('deviceName') + " " + record.get('description');
    metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + deviceDetail + '"';
    return value;
}
```

This is the place (metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + deviceDetail + '"';)  where you need to show data in tooltip

Comment: I ended up using this method, is much simpler :D. Thanks man!

Comment: It's nice solution, but why just not use:
renderer: getExpandableImage

when the parameters are exactly the same?

Answer (score 5):

you can use below example from sencha documents

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.tip.ToolTip

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    fields: ['company', 'price', 'change'],
    data: [
        ['3m Co',                               71.72, 0.02],
        ['Alcoa Inc',                           29.01, 0.42],
        ['Altria Group Inc',                    83.81, 0.28],
        ['American Express Company',            52.55, 0.01],
        ['American International Group, Inc.',  64.13, 0.31],
        ['AT&T Inc.',                           31.61, -0.48]
    ]
});

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Array Grid',
    store: store,
    columns: [
        {text: 'Company', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'company'},
        {text: 'Price', width: 75, dataIndex: 'price'},
        {text: 'Change', width: 75, dataIndex: 'change'}
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

var view = grid.getView();
var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
    // The overall target element.
    target: view.el,
    // Each grid row causes its own separate show and hide.
    delegate: view.itemSelector,
    // Moving within the row should not hide the tip.
    trackMouse: true,
    // Render immediately so that tip.body can be referenced prior to the first show.
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        // Change content dynamically depending on which element triggered the show.
        beforeshow: function updateTipBody(tip) {
            tip.update('Over company "' + view.getRecord(tip.triggerElement).get('company') + '"');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

When you declare the column use the property `attribute`:

```
{ 
  field: "nameField",
  width: "150px",
  title: "My Field",
  attributes: { title: "#=data.nameField#" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used in renderer:

```
function(value,metadata,record){
    metadata.attr = 'ext:qtip="' + val + '"';
}
```

Comment: sorry i missed closing of function

Answer (score 0):

Use your columns renderer function as follows:

```
{
                id       :'data',
                header   : 'Data', 
                width    : 160, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex: 'data',
                renderer : function(value, metadata,record) {
                    return setTooltip(value, metadata,record);
                }
            }


    function setTooltip(value, metaData, record){
        var deviceDetail = record.get('data') + ": " + record.get('description');
        metaData.attr='ext:qtip="' + deviceDetail + '"';
        console.log("deviceDetail: " + deviceDetail);
        return value;
    }
```