# ExtJS 4.2.1 - Grid in Tab Panel - Tooltips stop working

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a `Ext.grid.Panel` with Tooltips that work fine.

If I place the `Grid` inside an `Ext.tab.Panel`, 
and move

```
renderTo : 'inner',
```

onto the Tab panel, the tooltips no longer work

https://jsfiddle.net/95g1pdck/2/

Is there some adjustment I need to make for this to work?

Comment: Look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304785/add-tooltip-to-extjs-grid-to-show-complete-information-about-that-row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to render grid first.

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Array Grid',
        height: 200,
            store: store,

            columns: [
                {text: 'Company', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'company'},
                {text: 'Price', width: 75, dataIndex: 'price'},
                {text: 'Change', width: 75, dataIndex: 'change'}
            ],
        });
        var tabs = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            renderTo : 'inner',
            items : [ grid ]
        });
```

Just updated your fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/95g1pdck/4/

Comment: this works, but I believe there's still a minor race condition.  To be safe, it seems better to create the Tooltip in the listener for the view called `viewready`